# R: install package tkrplot. Error message: ld: cannont find -lXss

Tags: r, linux, xss, ld, opensuse

I want to install the tkrplot package for R on my opensuse42 computer using

> install.packages("tkrplot",dep=TRUE)

---

However, I get an error message and i dont know how to proceed.

> gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o tkrplot.so tcltkimg.o -L/usr/lib64 -ltcl8.6 -L/usr/lib64 -ltk8.6 -L/usr/lib64 -lX11 -lXss -lXext -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
>
> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lXss
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> /usr/lib64/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'tkrplot.so' failed
>
> make: *** [tkrplot.so] Error 1
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tkrplot’
>
> ´* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/tkrplot’

I already installed libXss1 via Yast, but this did not solve the problem.
I also have tk, tk-devel such as tcl, tcl-devel installed.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot find -lXss

-lXss means libXss.so

---

Opensuse42 : # `zypper in libXScrnSaver-devel`

Provides `/usr/lib64/libXss.so`